# Is there a simple way to load all c runtime dlls (ex. vcruntime140.dll) from a common custom location where my program is installed?

Tags: c++, c, dll

I would like to build all my C++ programs with /MD option in Visual Studio 2019 to reduce the size of the output binaries.
 However, I don't want my programs to load the c runtime dlls from the default location.
I don't want to keep them in my binary folder either, because I have multiple binary folders and I don't want to duplicate the c runtime dlls in all these folders.
Rather, I want to keep them in a common shared folder to avoid version conflicts when any system updates run.

Example:

C:\Program Files\MyProduct\Common          =>  should contain all C/C++ runtime dlls

C:\Program Files\MyProduct\tools\*.exe
C:\Program Files\MyProduct\libs\*.dll
C:\Program Files\MyProduct\Apps\*.exe

EXEs and DLLs from other folders should all use the C/C++ runtime dlls from the "C:\Program Files\MyProduct\Common" folder.

How this can be achieved ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably should just have your installer install the visual studio redistributable as part of the install process.

Comment: As  @drescherjm says and  _"...However, I don't want my programs to load the c runtime dlls from the default location...."_ why ?  And if you insist look into Manifests and Side-by-Side Assemblies https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/SbsCs/about-side-by-side-assemblies-

Comment: That goes against the philosophy of having shared C runtime libraries, which are patched by the system for security flaws etc. But you can certainly install CRT DLLs in your app's bin folder. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/choosing-a-deployment-method?view=msvc-160) for more info.